# Joomdle courses are not showing

Tags: joomla3.0, moodle, joomdle

I am facing a problem. I have Integrated Joomla and Moodle by using Joomdle. All are working fine. I am facing a problem. Before integrate I created courses in moodle and some users were enrolled into it. But After integration these courses are not showing in the Joomdle mycourses link. After integration, When I created new course and users are enrolled into it then it is visible in mycourse link. Please help me to sought it out.

Answer (score 0):

first check components->joomdle->system check . May be Moodle to Joomla cHTTP conn is down . If something is down joomdle docs will help you out of it . 
Also check components->joomdle->users . the acounts you are talking about must me check into joomla , moodle and joomldle if they are not try the migrate functions . Hope it helped

Comment: I had checked everything. System check and Joomdle users both are ok. But admin user is not got checked.